# How to automatically detect a specific feature from one image and map it to another mask image? Then how to smoothen only the corners of the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Using the `dlib` library I was able to mask the mouth feature from one image (masked).

##### masked

[image]

Similarly, I have another cropped image of the mouth that does not have the mask (colorlip).

##### colorlip

[image]

I had scaled and replaced the images (replaced) and using `np.where` as shown in the code below.

##### replaced

[image]

```
#Get the values of the lip and the target mask
lip = pred_toblackscreen[bbox_lip[0]:bbox_lip[1], bbox_lip[2]:bbox_lip[3],:]
target = roi[bbox_mask[0]:bbox_mask[1], bbox_mask[2]:bbox_mask[3],:]
cv2.namedWindow('masked', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('masked', target)


#Resize the lip to be the same scale/shape as the mask
lip_h, lip_w, _ = lip.shape
target_h, target_w, _ = target.shape
fy = target_h / lip_h
fx = target_w / lip_w
scaled_lip = cv2.resize(lip,(0,0),fx=fx,fy=fy)

cv2.namedWindow('colorlip', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('colorlip', scaled_lip)


update = np.where(target==[0,0,0],scaled_lip,target)
cv2.namedWindow('replaced', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('replaced', update)
```

But the feature shape (lip) in 'colorlip' does not match the 'masked' image. So, there is a misalignment and the edges of the mask look sharp as if the image has been overlayed. How to solve this problem? And how to make the final replaced image look more subtle and normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Update #2: OpenCV Image Inpainting to smooth jagged borders.

[OpenCV python inpainting](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html) should help with rough borders. Using the mouth landmark model, mouth segmentation mask from DL model or anything that was used the border location can be found. From that draw border with a small chosen width around the mouth contour in a new image and use it as a mask for inpainting. The mask I provided need to be inverted to work.

In input masks one of the mask is wider, one has shadow and last one is narrow. The six output images are generated with radius value of `5` and `20` for all three masks.

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
# import cv2 as cv2
# import cv2
import cv2.cv2 as cv2

img = cv2.imread('images/lip_img.png')
#mask = cv2.imread('images/lip_img_border_mask.png',0)
mask = cv2.imread('images/lip_img_border_mask2.png',0)
#mask = cv2.imread('images/lip_img_border_mask3.png',0)
mask = np.invert(mask)
# Choose appropriate method and radius.
radius = 20
dst = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, radius, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
# dst = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, radius, cv2.INPAINT_NS)
cv2.imwrite('images/inpainted_lip.jpg', dst)
cv2.imshow('dst',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

#### Input Image and Masks

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

#### Output Images

[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]

### **Update #1: Added Deep Image harmonization based blending methods.

Try [OpenCV seamless cloning](https://learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/) for subtle replacement and getting rid of sharp edges. Also [deep learning based image inpainting](https://github.com/JiahuiYu/generative_inpainting) on sharp corners or combining it with seamless clone may provide better results.

[Deep learning based Image Harmonization](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/deep-image-harmonization) can be another approach to blend together two images such that the cropped part matches the style of background image. Even in this case the pixel intensity will change to match the background but blending will be smoother. Links are added to bottom of the post.

#### Example

This code example is based on learnopencv seamless cloning example,

```
# import cv2
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np

src = cv2.imread("images/src_img.jpg")
dst = cv2.imread("images/dest_img.jpg")

src_mask = cv2.imread("images/src_img_rough_mask.jpg")
src_mask = np.invert(src_mask)

cv2.namedWindow('src_mask', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('src_mask', src_mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Where to place image.
center = (500,500)

# Clone seamlessly.
output = cv2.seamlessClone(src, dst, src_mask, center, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)

# Write result
cv2.imwrite("images/opencv-seamless-cloning-example.jpg", output)

cv2.namedWindow('output', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('output', output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

#### Source Image

[image]

#### Rough Mask Image

[image]

#### Destination Image

[image]

#### Final Image

[image]

#### Reference

- https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/df/da0/group__photo__clone.html
- https://learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/
- https://learnopencv.com/face-swap-using-opencv-c-python/
- https://github.com/JiahuiYu/generative_inpainting
- https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html

#### Deep Image Harmonization

- https://github.com/bcmi/Image-Harmonization-Dataset-iHarmony4
- https://github.com/wasidennis/DeepHarmonization
- https://github.com/saic-vul/image_harmonization
- https://github.com/wuhuikai/GP-GAN
- https://github.com/junleen/RainNet
- https://github.com/bcmi/BargainNet-Image-Harmonization
- https://github.com/vinthony/s2am

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But following the above method the lip color is completely changed and looks like a normal lip without any color applied. But I want to retain the new lip color as shown in the "replaced"image  and only smoothen the edges such that it blends naturally. Also could you please show how to find the exact center point in your example i.e (500,500).

Comment: I have added another method that could help with blending. As for `center point` I chose it randomly. It is the coordinate in background image where the cropped/masked is to be pasted.

Comment: I tried the seamless cloning technique but there is color change in the replacement part. As you have mentioned that the other technique based on deep learning also will change the background to adjust with the "replacement part". But I just want to apply blending on only the edge of the new replaced lip such that the patch should not be noticeable. For my case the color change is undesirable. Thank you!

Comment: Try alpha blending, https://learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/. Try with smooth border transition on grayscale alpha mask. Other than this I cannot think anything at the moment.

Comment: I have also added opencv based image inpainting.